# Ionic 2 image local directory copy not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-ios

Hi I can not copy the official local directory on the iPhone phone.
I'm getting an error at this function `copyFileToLocalDir`.
Whenever I get a picture from the phone's gallery and camera, I always get the error. After each photo on the android phone, each photo is on the local line. How can I get it?
Why does it work on **iOS** phones when working seamlessly on **Android** phones?

```
presentActionSheet(){
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title : "Resim Kaynağını Seçiniz",
      buttons : [{
        text : "Galeriden Seç",
        handler : ()=>{ 
this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
        }
      },{
        text : "Resim Çek",
        handler : ()=>{
          this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
        }
      }]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
  }
  takePicture(SOURCETYPE){
    var options = {
      quality : 25,
      sourceType : SOURCETYPE,
      destinationType : this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType : this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      saveToPhotoAlbum : false,
      correctOrientation : true
    };
    var yerelDizinAndroid;
    var yerelDizinIOS;
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath)=>{
      if(this.platform.is('android') && SOURCETYPE === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY){
        this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath).then(filePath =>{
          let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));
          yerelDizinAndroid = currentName;
          this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
        });
      }else {
      var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      yerelDizinIOS = currentName;
      this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
    }
    }, (err) => {
    this.presentToast('Herhangi bir işlem yapılmadı.');
  /*  this.file.removeDir(cordova.file.dataDirectory, yerelDizinAndroid);
    this.file.removeDir(cordova.file.dataDirectory, yerelDizinIOS); */
  });
}
  private createFileName() {
    var newFileName =  "S" + window.localStorage.getItem("auth_key") + ".jpg";
    return newFileName;
  }
  private copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName) {
    this.file.copyFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(success => {
      this.lastImage = newFileName;
    }, (error) => {
      this.presentToast('Görsel yerel dizine taşınamadı..');
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?  And just to be clear, it works fine on Android but not iOS right?

Comment: Yes, it does not work only on iOS phones @lintmouse

Comment: If it works on one platform but not the other its probably the restrictions/access rights on a specific platform. Make sure you are using the correct file path.  I don't think this is ionic-framework related, more like OS/Cordova related.

Comment: How can I get the file path correctly? @DanteTheSmith

Comment: That used to be HELL from what I remembered, I am not working with it for over a year now :( Best bet is to google application data storage with Cordova and start there?

Comment: "ERROR: Wrong type for parameter "uri" of resolveLocalFileSystemURI: Expected String, but got Null. " I am getting such an error. @DanteTheSmith

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem photo not showing in ios. here the solution
Add this :

```
import { normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';
```

and see this post [Ionic 3 - ios - displaying selected image on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702957/ionic-3-ios-displaying-selected-image-on-screen/47708792#47708792)