# Dowloaded Images and video not loading in Ionic 3(iOS). However works fine in Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using ionic 3 to build an app. I am using Cordova plugin for storing downloaded content locally and its reference in sqlite db. Everything works fine in Android but on iOS downloaded images are not showing neither the downloaded video is playing.
I am storing absolute paths of thumbnails and videos in db in this way -

```
platform.Is("iOS"){
    this.localdirectory = this.file.dataDirectory+filename;
}
else
{
    this.localdirectory = this.file.externalDataDirectory+filename;
}
```

Also in build to build upgrades I noticed that Application UUID changes in IOS.
Any solution?

Comment: which version of ios? ios 11?

Comment: @SurajRao Yes iOS 11

Comment: hmm.. maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702957/ionic-3-ios-displaying-selected-image-on-screen/47708792#47708792 is your problem

Comment: @SurajRao I tried using normalizeURL() but it is just appending '/' before 'file:///'. Should I just remove 'file:///' before storing that path in sqlite DB?

Comment: @SurajRao Also I don't see a solution to changing Application UUID. I am storing path of downloaded file in sqlite db and when I update the app, its UUID changes but that doesn't get moved to new container. So the path is essentially invalid now.

Comment: that could be an entirely different issue

Comment: @SurajRao Removing 'file:///' from path works for images. Currently my ionic version is 3.19.0, is that the reason why normalizeURL() is not working the way it should?

Comment: no thats fine.. because the function was added in 3.7.0..maybe raise a github issue with exact code and url string if it is not working

Comment: Thanks @SurajRao. I am new to ionic development. Just one more question. Is it the same reason why video's are also not playing? I am using  <video> tag to play video.

Comment: yes.. ios 11 enforces CORS. so the url needs to be normalized

Comment: Great help, Thanks a lot @SurajRao. I will raise seperate issue for changing uuid.