# ionic3 <img> tag src

Tags: html, angularjs, image, ionic3

I want take a picture and show it in iphone，I used 
    `<img [src]="imagePath"/>`
in home.html，and in home.ts, add cordova-plugin-camera to take a picture，
as following：

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
 quality: 100,
 destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,   //DATA_URL
 encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
 mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
 saveToPhotoAlbum: true,                                       
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageUri) => { //imageData, if DATA_URL

 //if DATA_URL
//let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
//this.imagePath = base64Image;       //the image can be show in screen


//if FILE_URI
this.imagePath = imageUri;});//cannot show image
},(err) => {// Handle error
});
```

I want to add image url in SQLite, so how can I fix it？

Comment: so..what is the issue?

Comment: picture cannot show in screen when I use imageUri

Comment: are you able to console log the url?

Comment: yes the url is right, but just cannot show. I find the reason right now!  Thanks all the same.

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702957/ionic-3-ios-displaying-selected-image-on-screen/47708792#47708792 ?

Comment: yes, its the answer, Thanks again!

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import { normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

```
<img *ngIf="base64Image" src="{{base64Image}}"/> 
   openCamera(pictureSourceType: any) {
let options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 95,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: pictureSourceType,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
  targetWidth: 400,
  targetHeight: 400,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
  correctOrientation: true
};
this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageData => {
    if (this.platform.is('ios'))
    this.base64Image = normalizeURL(imageData);
     // IF problem only occur in ios and normalizeURL 
     //not work for you then you can also use 
     //this.base64Image= imageData.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
  else
    this.base64Image= "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}, error => {
  console.log('ERROR -> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});
}
```