# Displaying image taken from camera

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

As you can see below, I am using the `[src]` attribute. What I am trying to do is preview the image taken from a device's camera. Please see the rest of the typescript code below.

```
<img [src]="lastImage" style="width: 100%" [hidden]="lastImage === null">
<button ion-button icon-left (click)="presentActionSheet()">
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>Select Image
</button>
```

Here is .ts code

```
lastImage: string = null;

public presentActionSheet() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        title: 'Select Image Source',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Load from Library',
                handler: () => {
                    this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Use Camera',
                handler: () => {
                    this.takePicture(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel'
            }
        ]
    });

    actionSheet.present();
}

public takePicture(sourceType) {
    // Create options for the Camera Dialog
    var options = {
        quality: 100,
        sourceType: sourceType,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: true
    };

    // Get the data of an image
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
        // Special handling for Android library
        if (this.platform.is('ios') && sourceType === this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
            alert('IF');
            this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath).then(filePath => {
                let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));

                // alert(correctPath);
                alert(correctPath + currentName);
                this.lastImage = correctPath + currentName;
                // this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
            });
        } else {
            alert('ELSE'); // This part runs
            var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            alert(cordova.file.dataDirectory + currentName); // This returns proper image path

            this.lastImage = cordova.file.dataDirectory + currentName;

            alert(this.lastImage); // this also has the image path.

            this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
        }
    }, (err) => {
        this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');
    });
}
```

Now when I choose image `Use Camera` then it opens the camera and I take a photo. But somehow the photo is not previewed in my above HTML where I am using `[src]="lastImage"`. What is wrong with my code that it does not show any image from the camera?

UPDATE

I also used `normalizeURL` which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702957/ionic-3-ios-displaying-selected-image-on-screen?rq=1) like following!

```
import { normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

this.lastImage = normalizeURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + currentName);
```

What happens with this piece of code is that it replaces `file:///` part with `http://localhost:8080` whereas I am taking a photo from the camera which local not any server and want to display that on img tag.

Comment: did you try this way ? src="{{lastImage}}"

Comment: No that does not seem to be working.

Comment: Try this <img *ngIf="lastImage " [src]="lastImage" style="width: 100%">

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj that does not work either. What happens is that img tag is not visible but when `lastImage` value changes then it does show img tag with width 100% however, the image that I took does not appear in that tag.

Comment: Can you share the application that has the issue?

Comment: @Keerthi I am not sure how can I share he application which I am working on. Do you mean the code?

Comment: Please mention this function too. 

    this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());

Answer (score 1):

He, I suggest that use base64 to set image to img tag, check the next code:

Controller atribute

```
private base64Image: any = false;
```

In your controller constructor set: "public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer" as parameter, this allow say to angular that the image is "safe".

Controller method

```
takePicture() {

const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 10,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
  // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
  // If it's base64:
  this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;

}, (err) => {
  this.message("Error, your camera device not work");
});
```

}

In your view file

```
<img *ngIf="base64Image != 'false'" [src]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(base64Image)">
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure if it is base64 because the image name ends in .jpg

Comment: Try sanitize the image, could be the solution.

Comment: If it is not base64 then it does not need any sanitization. here is the link for reference https://devdactic.com/ionic-image-upload-app/

Comment: I tried to sanitize image but still it didn't work. The same issue. It does take a photo but does not preview it.

Comment: He @null, in the book "Learn Ionic 2" available free in allitbooks [http://www.allitebooks.com/learn-ionic-2/] you can see an example of Ionic + camera that works properly, the same way that you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

<img *ngIf="base64Image" src="{{base64Image}}"/> 
   openCamera(pictureSourceType: any) {
let options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 95,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: pictureSourceType,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
  targetWidth: 400,
  targetHeight: 400,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
  correctOrientation: true
};
this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageData => {
    if (this.platform.is('ios'))
    this.base64Image = normalizeURL(imageData);
     // IF problem only occur in ios and normalizeURL 
     //not work for you then you can also use 
     //this.base64Image= imageData.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
  else
    this.base64Image= "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}, error => {
  console.log('ERROR -> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});
}
```

Comment: No way this still unresolved my issue. The preview of the image does not show up.

Comment: this part `this.base64Image= imageData.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');` of your code seems like it worked for me, but it always opens camera to take photo and preview it. I would also like to have access to photo library so if user wants to choose a picture from it instead of taking photo from camera.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, when i'm setting `src` to image tag in my localhost it is giving some unsafe security issue **ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME**.

so i used `DomSanitizer` to bypassSecurity like below.

```
constructor(private senitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

this.imageUrl = <string>this.senitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.imageUrl);
```

so check your console and if there is same problem, then instead of 'normalizeURL' use above code to bypass security for localhost.

or if you deploy your code on some secure domain `(https)`, it does not require security bypass.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it passes the LOCATION to the `src` (instead of URL).  You can:

1) Move the picture file (i.e from `C:/path/file.jpg` ) into the LOCALHOST's `www` root folder and use url `http://localhost/file.jpg` in `src` attribute.

or

2) convert/append image to `<canvas>` element ( but learn some basics of that)

or

3) As advised already, convert image to BASE64 string  (not nice way, but works) and append the data to `src`.

Answer (score 0):

May this code helps you

App Component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  video: any;
  canvas: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startup();
  }

  startup(): void {
    this.video = document.getElementById('video');
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    const nav = <any>navigator;
    nav.getUserMedia = nav.getUserMedia || nav.mozGetUserMedia || nav.webkitGetUserMedia;

    const self = this;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
      .then(function (stream) {
        self.video.srcObject = stream;
        self.video.play();
      });
  }

  onBtnClicked(event: Event): void {
    this.takePicture();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  takePicture() {
    const context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

And component's template is :

```
<div class="camera">
  <video id="video" #video
         width="width"
         height="height"
         (canplay)="onCanPlay($event)">
    Video stream not available.
  </video>
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" #canvas
        width="width"
        height="height">
</canvas>
<button (click)="takePicture()">Take Picture</button>
```

For detail check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Answer (score 0):

view template:

```
<img style="margin:5px; width: 100%" *ngIf="imageURL" src={{this.imageURL}} #myImage (click)="presentImage(myImage)" imageViewer/>

<button ion-button icon-left (click)="presentActionSheet()">
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>Select Image
</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Camera,CameraOptions, CameraPopoverOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { ImageViewerController } from 'ionic-img-viewer';
```

then add 'Camera' in providers:

```
@Component({
//.....
providers: [Camera],
//....
})
```

then initialize the given objects:

```
_imageViewerCtrl: ImageViewerController;
imageURL;
camera: Camera;
```

then

```
options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }


public presentActionSheet(){
      this.camera.getPicture(this.options).then((imageData) => {
         this.imageURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
         this.presentImage(this.imageURL);
      }, (err) => {
         console.log(err);
      });
  }

  presentImage(myImage) {
    const imageViewer = this._imageViewerCtrl.create(myImage);
    imageViewer.present();
  }
```